# Using gdata with only one user in app engine, need to decide

Tags: google-app-engine, gdata

I am building an GAE app that allows users to share documents over different contexts. Nothing too fancy.
I want to use Gdata in such a way that it is the app that owns the documents, and  not the users. This way, I shouldn't need any kind of tokens --one would think.

This is the main idea:

App user creates doc --> App creates doc and owns it --> user can RUD & share the doc

Is there any recommended way to authenticate using just a hard coded user & password?
The ClientLogin, up to now, seems to be the way to go.
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin.html

But I still have some doubts about the following:

1. Am I putting myself in a scenario of possible restrictions over other alternatives?
2. Is really ClientLogin the best way to go?

Could really use advice from others' experience here. Procrastination is killing me.

Cheers,

A.

Comment: Use OAuth instead of ClientLogin.  Is this something you are doing for a small set of users, or an  application intended for usage by anyone?

Comment: It's intended for a small and fixed set of accounts. The thing is I don't want users to own the documents, just CRUD them according to their roles. Is there any particular reason to use OAuth over ClientLogin? Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a personal project, and you've only got a very small group of users, the design might be OK.

One really good reason to use OAuth is that you won't need to store the account password somewhere.  Instead you'll be able to implement a simple 'setup' process to get and store an access token.  OAuth is also nice since you'll be able to restrict the access scope.

However, I must say, I find your question very vague -- so more specific answers are difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realize there is no code in my question, but it's because what I needed was to make a decision over using my account@google.com as the *only* owner of every document and then share with users, via access lists, or making users freely create and own documents with their own credentials. Your answer is what I was looking for, btw.